# Error message while trying to set a background in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the background of an Image View within a gesture event but I'm getting the error - Expression Expected , or )

Here is the code that giving me the issue

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    if (currentEvent == Event.single_tap) {
        mainMessage.setText("tap me twice");
        TopLeftArrow.setBackground(#000000);

        currentEvent = Event.double_tap;     //set to next desired event
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The error is showing up at the line

```
TopLeftArrow.setBackground(#000000);
```

Comment: `#000000` is a string maybe you have to add single quotes arround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant give background color like this

```
TopLeftArrow.setBackground(#000000);
```

Correct way is this

```
TopLeftArrow.setBackgroundColor(Color.parse("#000000"));
```